# Actualizar el valor de una columna de una BBDD

Tags: java, mysql, sql, wamp

Mi problema es que tengo que actualizar el campo TOTAL_IMPORTE de la tabla Clientes con la suma de los albaranes (que coincidan con el código de cliente, de la tabla Clientes, que meta el usuario)que se encuentran en la tabla Lineas.El código de cliente que introduce el usuario primero tengo que ver si existe en la BBDD. Y cuando ejecuto el programa me da el error de Before start of result set. **Todo esto en la BBDD de Almacen**.
Aquí dejo el código:

```
package BBDD;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejer9 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String cliente;
        int suma=0;
        System.out.println("Introduce el cod de cliente al que quieras que se le actualice el importe:");
        cliente=sc.nextLine();
        try {

            Connection primeraConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/almacen","root","");


            Statement a=primeraConexion.createStatement();

            ResultSet segundo=a.executeQuery("SELECT count( * ) as BINGO FROM `clientes` WHERE cliente LIKE "+"'"+cliente+"'");


            while(segundo.next()) {

                if (Integer.parseInt(segundo.getString("BINGO"))>0) {
                        //2. Crear objeto statement y metemos la sentencia SQL en un string para luego mediante el .executeUpdate insertarlo en la BBDD
                    Statement b=primeraConexion.createStatement();
                    Statement c=primeraConexion.createStatement();
                    ResultSet loQueActualiza=c.executeQuery("SELECT sum( precio ) as suma FROM lineas WHERE albaran = (SELECT albaran FROM albaranes WHERE cliente = (SELECT cliente FROM clientes WHERE cliente ="+"'"+cliente+"' ) )");
                    suma = Integer.parseInt(loQueActualiza.getString("suma"));
                    String actualizar="UPDATE `clientes` SET `TOTAL_FACTURA`="+"'"+suma+"' WHERE cliente LIKE "+"'"+cliente+"'";
                    //3. Comprobamos si se inserto la nueva tabla
                    b.executeUpdate(actualizar);
                    System.out.println("Datos insertados correctamente");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El cliente introducido no existe");
                }

            }           

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No es posible conectar con la BBDD.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta llamar a `.next()` sobre `loQueActualiza`:

```
    package BBDD;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejer9 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String cliente;
        int suma=0;
        System.out.println("Introduce el cod de cliente al que quieras que se le actualice el importe:");
        cliente=sc.nextLine();
        try {

            Connection primeraConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/almacen","root","");


            Statement a=primeraConexion.createStatement();

            ResultSet segundo=a.executeQuery("SELECT count( * ) as BINGO FROM `clientes` WHERE cliente LIKE "+"'"+cliente+"'");


            while(segundo.next()) {

                if (Integer.parseInt(segundo.getString("BINGO"))>0) {
                        //2. Crear objeto statement y metemos la sentencia SQL en un string para luego mediante el .executeUpdate insertarlo en la BBDD
                    Statement b=primeraConexion.createStatement();
                    Statement c=primeraConexion.createStatement();
                    ResultSet loQueActualiza=c.executeQuery("SELECT sum( precio ) as suma FROM lineas WHERE albaran = (SELECT albaran FROM albaranes WHERE cliente = (SELECT cliente FROM clientes WHERE cliente ="+"'"+cliente+"' ) )");
if (loQueActualiza.next()){
                    suma = Integer.parseInt(loQueActualiza.getString("suma"));
}
                    String actualizar="UPDATE `clientes` SET `TOTAL_FACTURA`="+"'"+suma+"' WHERE cliente LIKE "+"'"+cliente+"'";
                    //3. Comprobamos si se inserto la nueva tabla
                    b.executeUpdate(actualizar);
                    System.out.println("Datos insertados correctamente");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El cliente introducido no existe");
                }

            }           

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No es posible conectar con la BBDD.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```